# C# 'Could not find file' using File.Move() across network locations

Tags: c#, networking, file-io

I have a .dll that calls out to a service (IIS App pool) that I created. Both live on different servers on the network. The .dll calls out to the service. The service then creates a file and saves it on it's own drive. The service then returns the full path to this file back to the calling .dll. The .dll then attempts to File.Move() this file to another network drive. The Service is using the Application Pool Identity (to create and save the file) and the service account running the .dll has Modify access on both the source and destination folder. All of this has worked fluidly locally as well as in both our Dev and Test environments, however in our PROD environment I get this "File Not Found" error.

```
         <errors exceptionType="FileNotFoundException">
            <error Source="mscorlib" TargetSite="Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)">Could not find file 'filepath'.</error>
            <stack>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)</stack>
            <stack>   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)</stack>
         </errors>
```

'filepath' in the error is actually the full UNC path to the generated file. I have confirmed that the file DOES exist and copying the path included in the error into Windows Explorer opens the file no problem. I'm not sure what else to look at or consider. I've read as much conflicting info as possible regarding File.Move across network drives as I continue to bang my head against the wall trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's trying to use a mapped network path which is mapped for a user other than the one used for IIS.

Comment: @MatthewWatson the path being supplied to the File.Move method is structured like \\server\d$\foo\bar\output\file.bmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question. It appears the .dll was having trouble finding the network shared path. As I said in my original post, copying the path that was included in the error and pasting it into Windows Explorer opened the file without issue for me. However, the actual network path on the "Sharing" tab of the folder was not setup correctly so technically the path was wrong. Once we fixed the Network Path, the service ran successfully.